# check box value not saved properly in database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I write this from in Codeigniter as a `form_view.php`.

```
<?php echo form_open('form'); ?>

<h5>Man</h5>
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="m"/>

<h5>Lady</h5>
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="f" />

<h5>Username</h5>
<input type="text" name="username" value="" size="50" />

<div><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>

</form>
```

And then I add this data to the database like this:

```
  $data=array(
            'type'=> $_POST['options[]'],
            'name'=> $_POST['name']
            );
    $this->db->insert('user_data',$data);
```

The name field is ok. But the type field has nothing. I can not find the error. Please help me.

Comment: Please use the code formatting function in the editor!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want multiple values to be stored with comma (as separator) between them

```
$data=array(
        'type'=> implode(',', $_POST['options']),
        'name'=> $_POST['name']
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `[]` from options.

`$_POST['options']` will be an array. You may have to join the values to a string.

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions:

1. If neither one is checked the value will not be submitted to the database, so you need a default.
2. Consider using a radio type instead of checkbox. Except for some rare folks, I don't think too many people are going to be both man and lady.
3. Change $_POST['options[]'] to $_POST['options']

Answer (score 0):

Make

```
'type'=> $_POST['options[]']
```

as

```
'type'=> $_POST['options']
```